# Can I Install Ubuntu in sd3?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I was using Windows 7 some days ago. Accidentally, a magnet touched the HDD of my laptop. After few seconds, I got blue screen saying `crash dumping bla bla`. I shutdown my computer and when I started it, it says `automatic repair...` and the there was nothing.

I put my ubuntu live CD to see if I could format the HDD, Under Devices, I could only open the Z drive (/dev/sda3) and the System Reserved. I think, the magnet has deleted the files from sda2.

So, I just want to know if it's possible to install ubuntu in sd3 and make it bootable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to re-format the entire disk, provided no physical damage was done when you wiped it.

First start up the installer and see if you can create a new partition table. If this works you can continue to install as normal.

With regards to your question about installing to a single partition, yes you can. You will need to create a swap file instead of dedicating a partition. Read the Swap FAQ [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

Comment: The problem I am facing is that Gparted Partition Editor keeps scanning for devices but not able to find sda

Comment: If gparted doesnt allow you to create a new partition table then its goint to be hardware failure.